# How can I get user avatar link of facebook with userid

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I have id of user on facebook. Now I want to get user avatar base on the link https://graph.facebook.com on iOS.

Comment: Try this `http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture` where you can add user name like `sunnyleone`

Answer (score 6):

Try to use via this link :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=normal
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 3):

As i also gave you the first comment so explaining it.

If you looking the Avatar link try

`http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture`

where you can try the `username` like `sunnyleone` or you can use the `facebook userid` like for `sunnyleone` the userid is `131218490419638`.

if you looking your facebook id you can get it [from here.](http://findmyfacebookid.com/) for your examples.

And One Major thing that nobody checked Image size is small for you can add parameter like

`?type=normal`

or for more bigger image. But the best one is you can replace the redirect link like.

replace `_s` to `_n`

**Small Image :**
http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/t5/162024_131218490419638_623017319_s.jpg

**Big Image :** http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/t5/162024_131218490419638_623017319_n.jpg

then you can get the bigger Image.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

use `@"https://graph.facebook.com/uid/picture"` to get facebook profile picture

Answer (score 1):

```
  NSString *urlStr   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", userId];
  NSURL    *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
  NSData   *data     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  UIImage *image     = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```